# Tkinter opens the Filedialog twice to take the File

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two functions `CheckOs` and `_get_keyfile` as below:

**1:CheckOs(without considering Mac)**

```
def CheckOs():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        return "Windows"
    return "Linux"
```

**2:_get_keyfile**

```
def _get_keyfile(stdscr):
    keyfile = Tk()
    keyfile.withdraw()
    if CheckOs() == "Windows":
        keyfile.KeyfileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Selecta Key File",filetypes=(("Anfu Keyfiles", "*.anky"),))
    #if not windows then linux,IGNOREEEEEEEEE MAC
    keyfile.KeyfileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/home", title="Select a Key File",filetypes=(("Anfu Keyfiles", "*.anky"),))
    keyfile.destroy()
    return keyfile.KeyfileName
```

the problem is when ever `_get_keyfile` Function is executed it opens the File Dialog to select the file but opens again after I select the file and the file is selected after the second time. The problem only persists on Windows on Linux its working fine.

I want to know if I am doing something wrong or is that a bug in Tk .Any help Appreciated

Comment: Try adding a else when it is linux after the if ```else: #if linux```

Comment: Ok i will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `_get_keyfile` function change the function to include a else after the if to avoid opening dialog box. If it's not a Linux OS

```py
def _get_keyfile(stdscr):
    keyfile = Tk()
    keyfile.withdraw()
    if CheckOs() == "Windows":
        keyfile.KeyfileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select a Key File",filetypes=(("Anfu Keyfiles", "*.anky"),))
   
    else:
        keyfile.KeyfileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/home", title="Select a Key File",filetypes=(("Anfu Keyfiles", "*.anky"),))

    keyfile.destroy()
    return keyfile.KeyfileName
```

As a result the dialog box will only pop-up one time
Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank-you that was the problem.Aparently after executing the if block,the next block was being executed,Silly me

Comment: Happy to help you out!

Comment: Should `keyfile.destroy()` be outside the else block?

Comment: @acw1668 ah yes

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for the suggestion i made the edits!